# Jquery and CSS toggle menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, toggle

So I'm trying to make a jQuery menu that toggles from the left every time I click on this icon. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        if ($("#menu").css('left') == 0) {
            $("#menu").animate({
                left: "-190"
            }, "slow");
        } else if ($("#menu").css('left') < 0) {
            $("#menu").animate({
                left: "0"
            }, "slow");
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: what is your question??

Comment: It doesnt work, can someone help me please? Sorry for not being clear about it

Comment: @JonathanN What's the problem? What happens when you actually click?

Comment: nothing happens when I click

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

As fas as i understand from the code you provided , the

1st if check is the menu closed -> then open

and 2th logic statement elseif check is the menu opened -> then close it

Maybe its made like this for design reasons , but i just noticed:

`left: "-190"` change to `left: "+190"`

`$("#menu").css('left') < 0` hange to `$("#menu").css('left') > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the .slideToggle api

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Also could try the .show()/.hide() as well.

That will simplify your code a bit, unless you need it more complex.